# Change bibliography starting number

Tags: bibliographies, numbering

I am currently using the usual field `\begin{thebibliography}` for my references at the end of my scientific papers.
The numbers of the citations go from `[1]` to `[19]`, as usual.

I would like to change this. I would like that the starting number were `[9]`, to `[27]`, for the citations.

How could I do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Strange, but if you want...

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}


Let us cite \cite{a1},  \cite{a2} and \cite{a3}.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\makeatletter
\addtocounter{\@listctr}{8}
\makeatother

\bibitem{a1}
A1
\bibitem{a2}
A2
\bibitem{a3}
A3
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, that's what I needed! Many thanks from Italy to Poland! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Taken from: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15487

```
\begin{document}

\let\oldthebibliography=\thebibliography
\let\oldendthebibliography=\endthebibliography
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{
    \oldthebibliography{#1}
    \setcounter{enumiv}{8}                        % Change this number as required
}{\oldendthebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry for posting this as an answer, but I don't have enough karma to comment)
In addition to Nirmal's answer: You need to redefine `thebibliography` only when you use BiBTeX. Otherwise, you can just add the line `\setcounter{enumiv}{8}` under `\begin{thebibliography}[..]`.

Comment: That was already showed in Nirmal's answer, I think ...

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to redefine thebibliography. This is only necessary when using bibtex. When you write the bibliography by hand or use generated bbl, it is simpler.