# \bibliography{} starting from any number

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, numbering

I'm aware of a previous question about [changing bibliography starting number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114420/change-bibliography-starting-number), but my problem is that I'm not using `\begin{thebibliography}` to build the bibliography, but directly reading it from a bibtex file. Is there any method of changing the default numbering, e.g. starting from 10 instead of 1 when compiling? The end of my file is as follows:

```
% REFERENCES AND NOTES
\bibliography{bibtextfile}
\bibliographystyle{style}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\setcounter{enumiv}{9}`, at least `enumiv` is the counter used by the `article.cls` version of `\thebibliography` for the numbering

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work in my case. How can I check my counter type?

Answer (score 7):

`\setcounter{enumiv}{9}` would work if the the `\thebibliography` wouldn't apply `\usecounter{enumiv}` which in turn resets the `enumiv` counter.

From `article.cls`

```
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\refname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%   This is the 'culprit'!!!!!
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
```

and from `latex.ltx`

```
\def\usecounter#1{\@nmbrlisttrue\def\@listctr{#1}\setcounter{#1}\z@}
```

i.e. `\setcounter{#1}{0}` effectively.

The following code uses a dummy counter `mybibstartvalue` and sets the `enumiv` counter *after* `\usecounter{enumiv}` using a patch.

However, this code is only meant for `article.cls`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcounter{mybibstartvalue}
\setcounter{mybibstartvalue}{9}

\xpatchcmd{\thebibliography}{%
  \usecounter{enumiv}%
}{%
  \usecounter{enumiv}%
  \setcounter{enumiv}{\value{mybibstartvalue}}%
}{}{}



\begin{document}


\cite{Lam94}

\cite{GSM97}

\bibliography{biblio}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for this elegant answer!

Answer (score 1):

Taken from: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15487

```
\begin{document}

\let\oldthebibliography=\thebibliography
\let\oldendthebibliography=\endthebibliography
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{
    \oldthebibliography{#1}
    \setcounter{enumiv}{9}                        % Start reference from [10]
}{\oldendthebibliography}

\end{document}
```