# Change bibliography starting number.... doesn't work

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, numbering, counters

[\bibliography{} starting from any number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289457/bibliography-starting-from-any-number)

I'm following this,but it doesn't work for some [package](https://github.com/cvpr-org/author-kit/blob/bd06af0972e61dd4b436484bf78e8dc7500285a5/main.tex#L7)

Can anyone help how can do it with the package?