# LNCS Bibliography issues

Tags: bibliographies, lncs

I'm using the LNCS template, and I want to have two distinct bibliography's in my paper. The first one is called "**References**" and the second "**Online References**". I create two separate bibliography's for the effect.

The two bibliographies must be **distinct**, and I pretend they had a continuous enumeration, or different enumeration styles.

This is my current bibliography:
[image]

In **online references**, I want the enumeration starting on **number 6**, or using different enumeration like "roman style" "I".

There's some code:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem {ia4games}
Millington, Ian, and John David Funge. Artificial Intelligence for Games. Burlington, MA: Morgan Kaufmann/Elsevier, 2009. Print.
 ...
\end{thebibliography}

\renewcommand\refname{Online References}

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{video2}
"Video: Building the AI for Hearthstone." Gamasutra. GDC's Vault AI Summit, 25 Aug. 2014. Web. 7 Apr. 2016.

\end{thebibliography}
```

I tried to use different styles, but without success. Please healp!

Comment: Would you consider using `biblatex`?

Comment: i dont know how to use it, I tried this approach but without success http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114420/change-bibliography-starting-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to use the indications of the [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114420/change-bibliography-starting-number) you mention:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

  \bibitem {ia4games}
  Millington, Ian, and John David Funge. Artificial Intelligence for Games. Burlington, MA: Morgan Kaufmann/Elsevier, 2009. Print.
  ...
\end{thebibliography}

\renewcommand\refname{Online References}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
  \makeatletter
  \addtocounter{\@listctr}{5}
  \makeatother

  \bibitem{video2}
  "Video: Building the AI for Hearthstone." Gamasutra. GDC's Vault AI Summit, 25 Aug. 2014. Web. 7 Apr. 2016. \end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `llncs`, like the standard classes, uses `enumiv` for the bibliography. The argument to `\begin{thebibliography}` should not be empty.

Comment: @egreg: Initially, I tried  with `enumiv`, but it didn't work. What happens if the argument is empty, as in the O.P.'s code? Doesn't LaTeX use a default value?

Comment: The argument is used for setting the hanging indentation; as you see, it is wrong in your output. I tried `\addtocounter{enumiv}` with `llncs.cls` and it works.

Comment: @egreg: I didn't notice it. Thanks for pointing it. It's corrected now.