# Start bibliography from zero with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber, ieeetran

Since I'm a bit of a freak, I would like to enumerate the entries in my bibliography starting with [0] (rather than with [1]). Here is the relevant excerpt from my file:

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=ieee,citestyle=numeric-comp,sortcites=true,maxnames=99]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand*{\biblabelsep}{\labelsep}
\addbibresource{whatever.bib}
....
\begin{document}
...
\printbibliography
...
\end{document}
```

A solution [Change bibliography starting number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114420/change-bibliography-starting-number) is constructed explicitly for article.cls, but there is none for ieeetran. Any help?

Comment: It is not required to ask questions with a working code example (even though it almost always helps to make the question a little better), but I think if you provide code that looks like an MWE it should be an MWE. I suggest you remove the `...`  as they don't add anything (except for an error), replace `whatever.bib` with `biblatex-examples.bib` and actually `\cite` a few example entries. This makes it easier for people like me to get started: I always test my suggestions in an example document. Usually I can just copy the MWE and am good to go, but here I had to modify stuff before I could.

Comment: For future visitors and because it is so prominently mentioned in the title, let me mention that `IEEEtran` is a publisher class. As such it probably only makes sense to use it when publishing with the IEEE, in that case you should normally be using the BibTeX `.bst` styles of the IEEEtran package (or manual `thebibliography` if you like that sort of thing) and not `biblatex`. [Most publishers can not handle `biblatex` submissions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864). If you are not publishing with the IEEE you may want to consider using a simpler document class altogether.

Comment: The linked answer did not work because it was about `thebibliography`, which is not used by and (basically) incompatible with `biblatex`. The document class could theoretically play a role here, but was not the major issue.

Comment: Check this. https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15487

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The naive solution just redefines the field format for `labelnumber` to subtract one. That leaves us with labels starting at 0.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\the\numexpr#1-1\relax}
```

[image: The citation reads "0-2", the bibliography entries are labelled "0.", "1.", "2", ...]

Alternatively, you can use the proper interfaces to do this.

- Load `biblatex` with the option `defernumbers`
- Then call `\printbibliography` with the option `resetnumbers=0`

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[backend=biber, defernumbers, 
  bibstyle=ieee, citestyle=numeric-comp, maxnames=99]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand*{\biblabelsep}{\labelsep}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer}
\printbibliography[resetnumbers=0]
\end{document}
```

The documentation warns about `resetnumbers`:

> Use this option with care as `biblatex` can not guarantee unique labels globally if they are reset manually.

In this case you should be fine, especially if you only have one bibliography at the end.

If you play around with `resetnumbers` you may have to delete all auxiliary files and recompile from scratch if you change the values, because old settings can live on in the `.aux` file.