# biber references do not start at 1

Tags: bibliographies, biber

When I compile the following latex document the references by \printbibliography don't start from 1 but from 21. What could cause this ?
I have allready seen another solved [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447099/start-bibliography-from-zero-with-biblatex) with a workaround but as I only want it to do the default behaviour I think this should be the last option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}

\begin{document}\selectlanguage{english}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../img/nucleo_f303k8}
        \caption{Nucleo-F303K8}
        \cite{NUCLEO-F303K8-2021-01-29}
    \end{figure}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Like this:

[21] NUCLEO-F303K8 board information on manufacturer site. englisch. mbed. Jan. 29, 2021. url: https://os.mbed.com/platforms/ST-Nucleo-F303K8/.

Comment: you mean the first number in the printed list is `[21]` ? that would be odd, please post a document that can be run that shows that effect (we can not run as posted as we don't have sources.bib or the image (you can presumably delete the `\includegraphics` line without affecting the bibliography?)

Comment: you are using style=alphabetic so I wouldn't expect a number at all.

Comment: Thank you very much I played around by citing other entries and it seems like the "number" is actually generated from the name and the year. It was my mistake copying the \usepackage line without thinking about it. I now looked up what style=alphabetic does which confirmed my assumption that it is generated from the last name of the author and the year. In the first entry there was no author name so it only returned the year (20"21").

Comment: Im not sure if I should just delete this question now or if I should answer it.

Comment: I guessed as much. No harm in giving a self answer I think.

Answer (score 1):

The code I was using does not show the default behaviour because I copied the usepackage line from [this](https://www.heise.de/tipps-tricks/LaTeX-Literaturverzeichnis-erstellen-so-klappt-s-4401420.html) (german) tutorial.

In it another [style](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Biblatex_citation_styles) is choosen were the reference "number" is generated from the last name of the author and the year. The entry I used did not have an author so the reference number only contained the year (20"21").

If you want the default behaviour, simply remove the style option or explicitly write style=numeric.