# How to setup addtocounter{\@listctr}{} in \documentclass[]{a0poster}

Tags: bibliographies, numbering, tikzposter

2

I'm aware of a previous question about [Change bibliography starting number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114420/change-bibliography-starting-number) but my problem is that I have used the code

```
 \makeatletter
 \addtocounter{\@listctr}{4}
 \makeatother
```

however, it does not work in \documentclass[]{a0poster}.

main tex

```
\documentclass[portrait,a0b,final]{a0poster}
\usepackage{type1cm} 
 \usepackage{lmodern} 
 \usepackage[T5]{fontenc}

  \begin{document}

  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\section}[2]{}
  \begin{thebibliography}{99}
     \bibitem{JM}
         J.M. 
     \bibtem{CR}
         C.R
    \end{thebibliography}
    \endgroup}

   \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\section}[2]{}
 \begin{thebibliography}{99}

 \makeatletter
\addtocounter{\@listctr}{2}
 \makeatother

    \bibitem{JJ}
       J.J
    \bibtem{CA}
        C.A
     \end{thebibliography}
      \endgroup}

     \end{document}
```

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: As always on this site post a full, minimal self contained example that shows your problem. That makes it a lot easier for others to help you.

Comment: @ daleif I have edited my question. Can you help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: a full example means starting from`\documentclass` and finishing at `\enddocument`

Comment: @js bibra I have added an example in my question. Can you help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7IRr.png) when I compile [a minimal version of your code](https://pastebin.com/raw/QCegK5iF) where the numeration works as expected...

Comment: After I fixed the typos `\bibtem` -> `\bibitem` and two `}`, then it copmpiles just fine and lists `[1],[2],[3],[4]`