# How to cite articles in a reference?

Tags: citing, revtex

Certain APS journals require to cite references that are used in the supplement, but not in the main text, in the following way:

```
@misc{suppl,
    howpublished={See Supplemental Material at XXXX, which includes Refs. [xx-yy].}
}
```

That is, they should be included as new references in a reference description. Here, xx should be the number of the last reference of the main text + 1 and yy depends on how many new references there are in the supplement.

**Is there any way to do this using the \cite-command?**

I use revtex4-2 with the corresponding reference packages. I actually got this working simply by using \cite{...} entry of the .bib file as usual. However, I now cannot seem to reproduce the behavior I got initially. I suspect that things depend on the compilation order here, but I am not sure how. I can also not find anything on the topic in the revtex guide, but I may have missed something.

Comment: The standard way would be to use a footnote (placed at the first point the Supplemental Material is referenced), assuming you are using `footinbib`?

Comment: @DaiBowen Thanks for the comment! I’m afraid this is not the format the journal requests in my case. The editor specifically asked for the described format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146139/discussion-between-wolpertinger-and-dai-bowen).

Answer (score 1):

#### Manual manipulation of the bibliography

REVtex seems to use bibtex - supposedly, you do so, too. This will create a bbl file containing plain LaTeX, that can be directly used in a document, and has the structure

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
...
\bibitem{suppl}
    See Supplemental Material at XXXX, which includes Refs. [xx-yy].
...
\end{thebibliography}
```

(given you have citet the supplementary references in your paper, or included it via `nocite`).

When you are done with your manuscript, you can (1) save the bbl file under a new name `mybbl.tex`, (2) comment `\bibliography{...}` out and (3) include the references by `\input{mybbl}` at the end of your paper.

You can then always manually rearrange the sequence of bibitems in the bibliography, including the reference to supplement references.

#### Change numbering of references in the supplement

To change the starting number of the references (for the supplement xx), see the brilliant hack here:
[Change bibliography starting number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114420/change-bibliography-starting-number). Actually, it is even easier: insert `\setcounter{enumiv}{xx}` after `\begin{thebibliography}[1]`.
This will start reference numbers at xx+1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I understand correctly, this only addresses the issue of ordering though, right?

Comment: Maybe I did not get your problem exactly, and I did not have enough rep a few days ago to ask in the comments. Yes, I thought that you had problems to put the reference to suppl at the end of your bibliography, and assumed that the actual supplement is a separate TeX document. Putting \setcounter{enumiv}{341} in the supplements bibliography helps to start the numbering of references in the supplement at 342.

Are you processing supplement and main text in the same document?

Comment: The supplement is separate, but I really just mentioned it for background. The feature I want is independent: to cite a reference inside the bibliography entry.

Comment: Do you mean, your list of references should be
References
[1] Einstein. A (1908)...
...
[25] Olpertinger W (2022) the final world formula
[26] See Supplemental Material at XXXX, which includes Refs. [27-398].

And text: As already mentioned in [1, 17, 26] blabla

Comment: Or should you specify [xx-yy] more precisely, and your bibliography becomes
[1] Einstein. A (1908)...
...
[25] Olpertinger W (2022) the final world formula
[26] See Supplemental Material at XXXX, which includes Refs. [32-37].
[27] See Supplemental Material at XXXX, which includes Refs. [38-104].
[28] See Supplemental Material at XXXX, which includes Refs. [105-106].

and so on?

Comment: ... I somehow don't get it :-)
 Away for now

Comment: the first option. So one of the bib entries contains a reference to new entries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146227/discussion-between-ute-and-wolpertinger).